# SQL query variable in union + COUNT()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with an SQL query where i need to

```
 SELECT MachineID from TABLE1
```

and then

```
Count(Passfail) from TABLE2 WHERE MachineID= *MACHINEID
```

`from the SELECT` statement previously into a single table

Comment: Can you show us simplified table structure, sample data and expected output?

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  If, in the second query, you already know the machine id, then why do even need the first query?

Comment: TABLE1
has the machineID and machinename
TABLE 2
Passfail and machineID
what i need as output would be 

MachineID 1
PassFail 10


i apologize for the horrilbe explanation as im a complete beginner on this

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost written it right there. You need to read up a bit on joins and sql `group by` :

```
select T1.MachineId, count(T2.Passfail) from
Table1 T1 inner join Table2 T2 on T1.MachineId = T2.Machine Id
group by T1.MachineId
```

EDIT:
For a separate count depending on values of PassFail, I'd use:

```
select T1.MachineId, 
sum(case when T2.PassFail='pass' then 1 else 0 end) as 'pass',
sum(case when T2.PassFail='fail' then 1 else 0 end) as 'fail'
from Table1 T1 inner join 
Table2 T2 on T1.MachineId = T2.machineId 
group by T1.machineId
```

Comment: Hi there! thanks for the swift reply!
what if i have 2 count statements to put in? for example a count(passfail) WHERE passfail = "pass" and count(passfail) WHERE passfail = "fail"? would the statement be the similiar?

Comment: I've modified my answer to accomodate your new requirement @Xion

Comment: Thank you so much! this fits what i need

Comment: Glad to have helped.